# Kohana 3 + PhpExcel problem with xls export

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, phpexcel

I have integrated PHPExcel library with Kohana 3, and have some problem wiht output xls file. When I tried create xls file on server (save on server file system) everything is all right, but when i tried output it with header(), than file is corrupted and show me in Excel some weird characters.

My code in controller/action_index:

```
$this->auto_render = FALSE;

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
     ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world!');

$type = 'xls';
$mimes = Kohana::config('mimes');
$mime = $mimes[$type][0];

$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = "$mime; charset=utf-8;";
$this->request->headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="01simple.xls"';
$this->request->headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0';

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("php://output");`
```

Thank you for help and sorry for my english.

PS: when i try output pdf same way, everything looks all right, problem is only with xls and xlsx...

Answer (score 1):

I use kohana 3.2, and the following:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world!');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$this->response->body( $objWriter->save('php://output'));
$this->response->send_file(TRUE, '01simple.xls');
```

Notice the `$this->response->body()` and `$this->response->send_file()`.

This makes sense to me, you want to send a file in the RESPONSE, not send a file in the REQUEST.

Answer (score 0):

Kohana has a really nice function to force downloads called "send_file". Try this:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
     ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello world!');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

$this->request->response = $objWriter->save('php://output');
$this->request->send_file(TRUE, '01simple.xls');
```

I don't think you need to change the request headers, except for the charset encoding maybe.

Let Kohana do the magic (it checks the MIME type by the filename "01simple.xls" for example) ;). By the way, you don't need to disable auto_render since the send_file() function does it :)

More details: http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/Request#send_file

Comment: Dont work, sended file is empty (0Bytes). But thanks for interesting function, didnt know about send_file()...

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://szpargalki.blogspot.com/2011/02/phpexcel-kohana-framework.html).

For Excel5 format you must use:

`$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';`

For Excel2007 format:

`$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';`

Or can use ready-made [module kohana-phpexcel](http://github.com/dshovchko/kohana-phpexcel).

Comment: Thanks, but these formats didnt help, outputed file is still corrupted. For now i solved my problem this way: save generated xls on server and then download it from there whit hyperlink..., not ideal but work for now...

Answer (score 0):

I use this, and it works.

```
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');

// Save to the output buffer. Internally the writer creates a temporary
// file to zip it up, then copies it to the php output buffer/stream.
$writer->save('php://output');

$mime = File::mime_by_ext(strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)));
$size = ob_get_length();

$this->response->header('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
$this->response->header('content-type', $mime );
$this->response->header('content-length', (string) $size);

// Send all headers now
$this->response->send_headers();
```

I can't see how the other answers would work as ->save('php://output') doesn't return anything, so $this->response->body() gets nothing and simply acts as a getter - effectively a NOP.

If you're calling this from a Controller_Template class, you need to ensure that auto_render is set to false I believe.

Answer (score 0):

It's a far stretch, but I read a problem about this on [github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/728). The quick fix proposed is to change the header form something xls-like to `text/csv`. So in your code try this:

`$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = "text/csv; charset=utf-8;";`

or

`$this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = "text/csv;";`